# Python complex app design

Tags: python, plugins, structure

I'm trying to develop small application with submodules (plugins).
As far as I understand the principle of plug-ins - each plugin will get app instance on init, like this:

```
from plugins import Plug1, Plug2
from utils import Logger, Api

class App(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.Log = Logger()
    self.Api = Api()
    self.plugins = []
    self.plugins.append(Plug1(self))
    self.plugins.append(Plug2(self))

class Plug1(object):
  def __init__(self, app):
    self.app = app

class Plug2(object):
  def __init__(self, app):
    self.app = app
```

App class has some attributes like logger and network api. How it will be more correct to use them in the plugin?
Use **self.app.Log** and **self.app.Api.func1()** or make shortlinks like

```
class Plug1(object):
  def __init__(self, app):
    self.app = app
    self.log = app.Log
    self.api = app.Api
```

Or maybe i'm totaly wrong with application structure?

Comment: Seems sort of like a personal preference issue. But, for what it is worth, this is pretty much the way I handle similar types of issues.

Comment: `self.log = app.Log` Every `plugin` require separate `log`, **can't call any plugin if `main` is executed** (use visible as plugin manager ).